# Haskell: How to make side effects in a RWS monad strict

Tags: haskell

I am trying to write a program which has an FFI to C. There is a method that needs to be called on a pointer, which does not return anything. My pointer is a state in the RWS monad, but when I try to change the state, the function is not called due to lazy-ness. How do I make sure that the function is called ?

Eg. In the following code how do I display "creating outer monad" ?

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
module Main where

import Control.Monad.RWS.Strict

newtype OuterMonad a = OuterMonad {
    unwrapOuterMonad :: RWST () () () IO a
} deriving (Monad, MonadIO)


createOuterMonad :: OuterMonad ()
createOuterMonad = do
    liftIO $ putStrLn "creating outer monad"
    return ()

runOuterMonad :: OuterMonad a -> IO ()
runOuterMonad _ = putStrLn "RunOuterMonad!!"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "starting Program"
    runOuterMonad $ do
        createOuterMonad
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should evaluate at some point the `OuterMonad`. For example here:

```
runOuterMonad :: OuterMonad a -> IO ()
runOuterMonad m = do
    evalRWST (unwrapOuterMonad m) () ()
    putStrLn "RunOuterMonad!!"
```

Comment: `liftIO`, while not wrong, isn't needed here, as the result type of `runOuterMonad` is just `IO ()`.

Comment: @kosmikus, you are right, I'm so used to write `liftIO` while dealing with monad transformers that I don't even realize I'm typing it.